# Ranking in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a data stream that consists of data like this.

```
{Student, Class, CurrentScore}
```

I want to use a sliding window to calculate the statistic of these events:

```
spark.readStream(...).withColumn("processingTime",..).
window(col("processingTime"), "30 minutes", "5 minutes"), col("class"))
```

But now i want to take out the top 3 students by each class in this window, but the Structured Streaming apparently does not support `rank()`

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting operations (also rank()) are supported on streaming Datasets *only* after an aggregation and in Complete Output Mode; straight from the manuals.

Complete Output Mode is however not a realistic way of working. I would rather write to a location that is converted to a columnar format eventually, and then query and rank with an appropriate query tool.